# How could I find the resolution of a display running Python3 on Linux?

Tags: python, linux

I've tried the following methods but none would work on Linux

```py
from win32.win32api import GetSystemMetrics


print(GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

```py
from ctypes import windll


info = windll.user32


print(info.GetSystemMetrics(0), info.GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

Comment: Tried using tkinter? `from tkinter import *` and `root = Tk()` and `root.withdraw()` and `root.winfo_screenheight()` and `root.winfo_screenwidth()`

Comment: @CoolCloud If you've got a good solution with `tkinter`, it would be worth posting an answer. I posted one using `xlib` but that is not in the standard library, so obviously if there is something with `tkinter`, that would be an advantage. But it would be good if there is a way in tkinter that does not involve opening a new window (even if only temporarily).

Comment: @alani Nope, i dont think so, `tkinter` needs a window, but try my answer out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `tkinter`, like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

height,width = root.winfo_screenheight(),root.winfo_screenwidth()
print(height,width)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Why the `mainloop()`?

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [xlib](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/):

```
import Xlib.display
display = Xlib.display.Display()
screen = display.screen()
print(screen.height_in_pixels, screen.width_in_pixels)
```

Comment: Nice to see how wonderful platform-independent is the Python! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The following link had a good answer https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/08/18/getting-your-screen-resolution-with-python/

I had to modify the last line to make it run in Python 3.

```py
import subprocess
cmd = ['xrandr']
cmd2 = ['grep', '*']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdin=p.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdout.close()
resolution_string, junk = p2.communicate()
resolution = resolution_string.split()[0]
width, height = resolution.split(b'x')
```

Comment: If you are going to parse the result of an external command, I would be inclined to use `xwininfo -root` and look for the `-geometry` line (or indeed, the `Width` and `Height`)